# An approximate eigenvalue that is not an eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Could you please help me understand why $\lambda$ in the example below is not an eigenvalue? It's easy to see that each $\lambda_n$ is an eigenvalue but I am having difficulty ascertaining that their limit is not.

Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: If $x$, the associated eigenvector,  was in the span of the $e_n$ , $x=\sum x_ne_n$ then we need $\lambda_nx_n=\lambda x_n$ contradicting the assumption that $\lambda_n\neq \lambda$.  If $x$ is not in the span it can't be an eigenvector (as $Tx$ is in the span).

Comment: @lulu Why is $Tx$ in the span ? Should it not rather be the closure of the span ? Although the overall argument still holds, of course

Comment: @Astyx  you are correct, I was too hasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the comments of lulu :

Let $x$ be an eigenvector and $\mu$ the associated eigenvalue. 
If $x$ is in the span of the $e_i$s, we would have $\mu = \lambda_n$ for some $n$ and therefore $\mu\ne \lambda$.

Otherwise, since $$\mu x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lambda_n \langle x, e_n\rangle e_n$$
is in the closure of the span of the $e_n$, either :

- $\mu \ne0$ and $x$ is in the closure of the span of the $e_i$ in which case by continuity of $x \mapsto \langle x, e_n \rangle$, $\mu = \lambda_n$ for some $n$, therefore $\mu\ne \lambda$.
- or $\mu =0$ in which case $\langle x, e_n\rangle =0$ for all $n$, ie $x\in Span(e_n)^{\bot}$. Thus you also need $\lambda \ne0$ or $Span(e_n)^{\bot} = \{0\}$ (that is, the $(e_n)$ being an orthonormal **basis**) for the statement to hold (the reverse implication being rather straightforward).